# Can someone explain why Leetcode won't accept this code?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain why this code isn't showing the right output on Leetcode?[image: Question:]

The testcase is

```py
tokens=["10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","17","+","5","+"]
```

Leetcode is saying the output generated with this code is 12, but when I try it on VScode and Online Python interpreter I'm getting the correct answer which is 22.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def evalRPN(self, tokens):
        """
        :type tokens: List[str]
        :rtype: int
        """
        stack,top=[],-1
        for i in tokens:
            if i[0]=='-' and len(i)>1:
                stack.append(int(i))
                top+=1
            elif i.isdigit():
                stack.append(int(i))
                top+=1
            elif i=="+":
                stack[top-1]=stack[top-1]+stack[top]
                stack.pop()
                top-=1
            elif i=="-":
                stack[top-1]=stack[top-1]-stack[top]
                stack.pop()
                top-=1
            elif i=="*":
                stack[top-1]=stack[top-1]*stack[top]
                stack.pop()
                top-=1
            else:
                stack[top-1]=int(stack[top-1]/stack[top])
                stack.pop()
                top-=1
        return stack[top]
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Please don't post image, copy and paste your code. Also the text of the question or link to it will be useful.

Comment: leetcode is probably testing with a different input than what you are given as an example, You have not adhered to the requirements of the question, which is that any of the operands may be another expression! You must support arrays of arrays

Comment: since it is reverse polish, simply flattening the array should do the trick

Comment: @Geoduck I don't understand. What do you mean leetcode is using a different input than the example I was given? The testcase I provided was the testcase that leetcode used, and leetcode is saying that my output is 12.

Comment: With some simple debugging, you will see that `int(6 / -132)` evaluates to -1 instead of 0 (I believe that's a Python 2 behavior). One more vote down for your not pulling enough weight.

Comment: `:type tokens: List[str]` and `:rtype: int` are not valid syntax. The way to annotate these types is on the `def` line: `def evalRPN(self, tokens: List[str]) -> int:`. But keep in mind that this requires `from typing import List` (in more recent versions of Python, you can use `list[str]` instead for the annotation, and skip the import); and that such type annotations have **no meaningful effect at runtime** and exist **solely for use by external tools**.

Comment: You can get LeetCode's result in Python 2.7, for the reason that was already pointed out in the code. But in this **legacy** version of Python that has been **officially unsupported since January 1, 2020**, you would not be able to annotate types at all. If LeetCode is expecting you to use it, something is seriously wrong, and you should be complaining to the site.

Comment: Before asking more questions, **please read** [ask] and [mre]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: @ChrisFu How was I to know that Python 2 in particular behaves this way? Just because it was a simple mistake doesn't mean I didn't try to fix the issue on my own or didn't "pull enough weight'. What good does downvoting achieve?

Comment: @georgebibu It's acceptable that you don't know this Python 2 behavior. It's NOT acceptable that you didn't try to pin the problem.